# How to resize and image and save as byte array

Tags: vb.net, winforms, bitmap, encoder, .net-4.7.2

I'm trying to let the user select an image file, then resize the image to a couple different sizes if needed, then save the resized images to byte arrays that will be saved into a database.  I keep getting errors when converting the image to a byte array (but only if the image was resized).  Hopefully someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

FYI, I'm not a professional programmer and usually get major criticism when I post my code.  I'm definitely open to any feedback or suggestions you may have so please be nice..lol

I usually get this error in the SaveImage() function on the Image.Save(mStream, TheImage.RawFormat) line
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder'

Sometimes I get a framework error and can't really tell where error occurs.

EDIT: I ended up extending the Image class which seems to be working pretty good so far.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO

Module Extentions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function GetBytes(ByRef bc As Image, Optional Format As ImageFormat = Nothing) As Byte()
        'Converts Image to Byte Array
        If Format Is Nothing Then Format = ImageFormat.Jpeg
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
            bc.Save(mStream, Format)
            Return mStream.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ReSize(ByRef bc As Image, MaxWidth As Integer, MaxHeight As Integer) As Image
        'Resize image to fit within MaxWidth & MaxHeight while keeping aspect ratio
        If MaxWidth < bc.Width Or MaxHeight < bc.Height Then
            Dim Scale As Double = Math.Min(MaxWidth / bc.Width, MaxHeight / bc.Height)
            Dim NewWidth As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(bc.Width * Scale))
            Dim NewHeight As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(bc.Height * Scale))
            Return New Bitmap(bc, New Size(NewWidth, NewHeight))
        Else
            Return bc
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Now my code in the form I was working on is much simpler..

```
    Private Sub SelectImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectImage.Click
        Dim Popup As New OpenFileDialog
        With Popup
            .Filter = "Images|*.gif;*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp"
            .Title = "Select Image"
            .FileName = ""
            .FilterIndex = 1
            .Multiselect = False
            .RestoreDirectory = True
        End With

        If Popup.ShowDialog = vbOK Then
            'Load Image from disk
            OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(Popup.FileName)

            'Resize and display image on form
            Picture.Image = OriginalImage.ReSize(200, 150)

            'Save Large Image
            FullImage = OriginalImage.ReSize(400, 300).GetBytes

            'Save Small Image
            SmallImage = OriginalImage.ReSize(100, 75).GetBytes

            ImageSelected = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here's my original code...

```
    Private OriginalImage As Image
    Private FullImage As Byte()
    Private SmallImage As Byte()
    Private ImageSelected As Boolean
```

```
Private Sub SelectImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectImage.Click
        Dim Popup As New OpenFileDialog
        With Popup
            .Filter = "Images|*.gif;*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp"
            .Title = "Select Image"
            .FileName = ""
            .FilterIndex = 1
            .Multiselect = False
            .RestoreDirectory = True
        End With

        If Popup.ShowDialog = vbOK Then
            'Load Image from disk
            OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(Popup.FileName)

            'Resize and display image on form
            Picture.Image = ResizeImage(OriginalImage, 200, 150)

            'Save Large Image
            Dim ResizedImage As Image = ResizeImage(OriginalImage, 400, 300)
            FullImage = SaveImage(ResizedImage)

            'Save Small Image
            ResizedImage = ResizeImage(OriginalImage, 100, 75)
            SmallImage = SaveImage(ResizedImage)

            ImageSelected = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function ResizeImage(ByRef InputImage As Image, MaxWidth As Integer, MaxHeight As Integer) As Image
        'ReSize the Image if needed to save space in the database
        If MaxWidth < InputImage.Width Or MaxHeight < InputImage.Height Then
            'ReSize Image
            Dim Scale As Double = Math.Min(MaxWidth / InputImage.Width, MaxHeight / InputImage.Height)
            Return New Bitmap(InputImage, New Size(Math.Round(InputImage.Width * Scale), Math.Round(InputImage.Height * Scale)))
        Else
            'Image size was OK
            Return InputImage
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function GetImage(ImageData As Byte()) As Image
        'Converts Byte Array to Image
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream(ImageData)
            Return Image.FromStream(mStream)
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function SaveImage(TheImage As Image) As Byte()
        'Converts Image to Byte Array
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
            TheImage.Save(mStream, TheImage.RawFormat)
            Return mStream.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function


    'These are functions I was playing around with because I was getting
    'System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder'
    'in the SaveImage() function on TheImage.Save(mStream, TheImage.RawFormat)
    'and I wasn't using the encoder parameter. I couldn't get these to help me though.

    Private Function SaveImage2(TheImage As Image) As Byte()
        'Converts Image to Byte Array
        Dim CodecInfo As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg")
        Dim Parameters As New Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
        Parameters.Param(0) = New Imaging.EncoderParameter(Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 75L)
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
            TheImage.Save(mStream, CodecInfo, Parameters)
            Return mStream.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function GetEncoderInfo(MimeType As String) As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
        Dim encoders As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo()
        encoders = Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        For j As Integer = 0 To encoders.Length - 1
            If encoders(j).MimeType = MimeType Then Return encoders(j)
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: Use the [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net) library

Comment: `TheImage.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Png)`.

Comment: To be more specific, when you generate a new Bitmap in memory, the RawFormat is set to `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`. You cannot save an Image with that format (it's not a *real* format). Btw, from what I can see, you should set `Option Strict On` and fix the issues, before you get distorted Images or Image sizes that don't exactly *match* the expected values.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something like that.  I just didn't know how to set the format with ImageFormat.Png. I turned option strict on and see what you mean about doubles/integer conversions, I'll fix that as well.  If you want to post you're comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new Bitmap with this constructor:

```
new Bitmap([OriginalImage], [Width], [Height])
```

you may think that the `[OriginalImage]` format is taken into consideration. It's not. A new raw Bitmap is created with the size specified and the `[OriginalImage]` is drawn inside the new container.
The new Bitmap object is created in memory and its [ImageFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat) is **`ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`**.
This `ImageFormat` doesn't have an Encoder/Decoder.

When you save the Image using the [Image.Save(Stream, Format)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_IO_Stream_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_) method overload passing the new Bitmap object `RawFormat`, you're passing `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`.
The Image class then tries to get the encoder from the `ImageFormat` specified (using the internal [FindEncoder()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ImageFormat.cs,170) method), which of course returns `null`, causing the exception:

> *System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   encoder'*

You can test it yourself, trying to get the Encoder/Decoder from the `OriginalImage` and the `ResizedImage` objects (using [ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo.getimagedecoders) or [ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo.getimageencoders)):

```
Dim originalCodec As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().
    FirstOrDefault(Function(cc) cc.FormatID.Equals(ResizedImage.RawFormat.Guid))
```

You'll see that when you try to get the Encoder/Decoder for the `ResizedImage` format, `originalCodec` will be null (`nothing`), while it'll return an Encoder/Decoder for the `OriginalImage` format.

Since the predefined `ImageFormat` is `ImageFormat.Png`, you can change your method to set this format when saving the Image to `MemoryStream`:

```
Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
    TheImage.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Png)
    Return mStream.ToArray()
End Using
```

<sub>Something that is also done internally in more than one occasion.

For example: [Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,645)</sub>